# Citation in the title of a subsection

Tags: citing

I cannot put a `\cite{}` in the title of a subsection `\subsection{...}`. I have tried to put the citation in a box, etc... No way. Is it possible ? I use also the package `multibib` because I have several kinds of references, and the bibliography style `habbrvyr-reverse` for all of them but two for which I use `alpha` and `habbrvyr-iterate` respectively. The LaTex class of the document is `article`.

Comment: Use the cite in the introduction sentence of your section.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes it is indeed the only solution I have found.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ, whether it generates numeric-style authoryear-style citation call-outs, and whether you employ a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`.

Comment: @Mico The question is edited.

Comment: Can you please post a MWE that creates this problem?

Comment: Do you mean multibib rather than multilib? Do make a short demonstration document.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau  Yes multibib. Yes I will by tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to put `\protect` before the modified `\cite` command.

See for example [here](https://guido.vonrudorff.de/2014/multibib-and-citations-within-figure-environment/).